# Creating a global stack variable inside a function in C

Tags: c, stack, blackjack

I'm trying to code a terminal blackjack game, i'm new in C programming

What i'm trying to do, is to create a global stack inside a function where i can put all my shuffled cards (52 cards) by pushing them one by one. And then, every player can pop() a card or two.. and the number of cards decrease in the stack..

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "stack.h"

/*  ***********************************************************************  */
/*                            STACK DATASTRUCTURE                           */
/*  ***********************************************************************  */

int stack[52];
void push();
int pop();
void traverse();
int is_empty();
int top_element();
int top = 0;


void push(int value) {
   stack[top] = value;
   top++;
}

int pop() {
   top--;
   return stack[top];
}

void traverse() {
   int d;

   if (top == 0) {
      printf("Stack is empty.\n\n");
      return;
   }

   printf("There are %d elements in stack.\n", top);

   for (d = top - 1; d >= 0; d--)
      printf("%d\n", stack[d]);
   printf("\n");
}

int is_empty() {
   if (top == 0)
      return 1;
   else
      return 0;
}

int top_element() {
   return stack[top-1];
}



/*  ***********************************************************************  */
/*                                MY FUNCTIONS                               */
/*  ***********************************************************************  */


void FYshuffle (int *array, int len) {
    int i, tmp, x;
    for (i=len-1; i>1; i--) {
        x = rand()%i;
        if (x==i) continue;
     /* now swap */
        tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[x];
        array[x] = tmp;
    }
}

int shuffleCards(void) {
    int i;
    int c = 0;
    int cards[52] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ,10 ,11 ,12 ,13 ,14 ,15 ,16 ,17,
                    18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32,
                    33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47,
                    48, 49, 50, 51, 52};
    int deck[52];

    srand(time(0));
    FYshuffle(cards,52);

    for (i=0; i<52;i++) {
      push(cards[i]); <<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE'S THE PROBLEM, ITS JUST LOCAL STACK! I NEED IT TO BE GLOBAL
      int element;
      element = pop();
      printf("Element removed from stack is %d.\n", element);
    }

    for (i=0;i<52;i++) {
      deck[i] = cards[i];
      printf("%d", deck[c]);
      printf("%s", " ");
      c++;
    }
    return 0;
    /* return deck; */
}


/* recognize suits */
int recognizeSuit(int num) {
  int suite;
  suite = num / 13;
  switch(suite) {
    case 0 :
      printf("Clubs ");
      break;
    case 1 :
      printf("Diamonds ");
      break;
    case 2 :
      printf("Hearts ");
      break;
    case 3 :
      printf("Spades ");
      break;

    default :
      printf("Error ");
  }
}

/* recognize the number */
int recognizeNumber(int num) {
  /* recognize the suit */
  int number;
  number = num % 13 + 1;
  switch(number) {
    case 1 :
      printf("ACE ");
      break;
    case 11 :
      printf("JACK ");
      break;
    case 12 :
      printf("QUEEN ");
      break;
    case 13 :
      printf("KING ");
      break;

    default :
      printf("%d ", number);
  }
}


int main(void) {
  shuffleCards();
  printf(" - ");
  recognizeNumber(2);
  recognizeSuit(2);


  return 0;
}
```

i just wrote a note in the code to show you guys the problem, how can i solve it? because when i check the stack in the main, it's empty..

thank you very much for the help! have a blessed day!

Comment: Why not declare the array `int cards[52]` inside `main` and pass a pointer to the function?

Comment: When your program starts the global stack[] is empty. In your first loop you push a card onto stack[] and immediately pop it off again. So the stack is empty again. After 52 loop iterations stack[] is still empty.

Comment: @user5329483 You should post that comment as an answer.

Comment: @user5329483 ah thank you very much, you just gave me the solution

i will try to be more careful the next time!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem you actually mentioned in your code is not correct. The stack you declare is already a global stack as you defined it globally.

You can test it right through. Here's a function named `pushGlobalStack()` where you can push values inside the function. And then for checking whether the stack is global or not, pop the values inside main instead of `pushGlobalStack()` function. You can check that values are exactly same.

```
void PushGlobalStack(){

int cards[52] = {11, 22, 51, 4, 5, 41 ,7 ,8 ,9 ,10 ,1 ,2 ,13 ,14 ,15 ,16    ,17,
                18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32,
                33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 6, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47,
                48, 49, 50, 4, 3};

for(int i=0; i<52;i++) {

    push(cards[i]);
   }
}

int main(void) {

 //shuffleCards();
 // printf(" - ");
 //recognizeNumber(2);
 //recognizeSuit(2);

 PushGlobalStack();

 for(int i=0; i<52;i++) {

    printf("%d \t", pop());

  }

 printf("\n\n\n");

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, i've found the problem, and thanks for the tip, i will use it asap! i've accepted the answer as a solution